# Unable to parse MP4 files -MemoryAllocationException: Tried to allocate X bytes, but the limit for this record type is:Y

Tags: metadata, apache-tika, tika-server

I am using Tika server to fetch metadata and contents of various file formats. I am using server with fileUrl enabled.
When parsing .mov file which are created using quicktime screen record, it gives me the following error.

> Text extraction failed (null) org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException:
> Unexpected RuntimeException from
> org.apache.tika.parser.mp4.MP4Parser@354bc1a2     at
> org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:293)
> at
> org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
>
> Caused by: org.mp4parser.MemoryAllocationException: Tried to allocate
> 1399026269 bytes, but the limit for this record type is: 536870912. If
> you believe this file is not corrupt, please open a ticket on github
> to increase the maximum allowable size for this record type.  at
> org.mp4parser.tools.MemoryUtils.allocateByteBuffer(MemoryUtils.java:30)
> at org.mp4parser.support.AbstractBox.parse(AbstractBox.java:100)    at
> org.mp4parser.AbstractBoxParser.parseBox(AbstractBoxParser.java:115)

The size of the file is just 20Mb. Other type of .mov files with

> content-type="video/quicktime"

is getting parsed with out any error. I connected the debug port and i see that it fails when converting to new IsoFile().

Any help to fix this is highly appreciated.

I start the server as shown below.

> java -jar tikaserver-1.24.1.jar -enableFileUrl -enableUnsecureFeatures

Comment: That file looks corrupt. A 20mb file shouldn't be requesting a chunk of data that huge!

Comment: Thanks @Gagravarr .but I can play that in quicktime. it happens to all such files from different users. I created this file using quicktime screen record on Mac.

Comment: I can play these files without any issues in quicktime player. Is there any other way I can check if this is corrupted?

Comment: https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser/issues/284 - looks related.